# How to get column names that has NA as column name

Tags: r

I am cleaning up excel files and one of the task is to get the column names correct. In the process, I get NA for some of the column names. In all such cases I want to fill in the value of the first row of that particular column.

A minimal example is as follows:

```
structure(list(c(NA, "1"), c(NA, "FOB"), c(NA, "WEH, Nr. Oberoi"
), c("W", "60"), c("H", "10"), c(NA, "1"), c(NA, "600"), c(NA, 
"01.01.19"), c(NA, "31.01.19"), c(NA, "30"), c("Vendor", "Capital"
), c("Display Cost", "900000"), c(8L, 0L)), .Names = c("Sr. No.", 
"Media Vehicle", "Location", "Size", NA, "Qty", "Area", "Start Date", 
"End Date", "Duration", "CTU", NA, "2"), row.names = 4:5, class = "data.frame")
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
structure(list(c(NA, "1"), c(NA, "FOB"), c(NA, "WEH, Nr. Oberoi"
), c("W", "60"), c("H", "10"), c(NA, "1"), c(NA, "600"), c(NA, 
"01.01.19"), c(NA, "31.01.19"), c(NA, "30"), c("Vendor", "Capital"
), c("Display Cost", "900000"), c(8L, 0L)), .Names = c("Sr. No.", 
"Media Vehicle", "Location", "Size", "H", NA, "Area", "Start Date", 
"End Date", "Duration", "CTU", "Display Cost", "2"), row.names = 4:5, class = "data.frame")
```

I tried using an if condition, but since there are three NA's in the names, not sure if I have to use a for loop to iterate over each na values.

```
if (is.na(names(dat))) {
  b <- which(is.na(colnames(dat)))  
  names(dat)[b][1] <- dat[1,b] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first find `NA` index in the names and then use those index to subset from the first row of the dataframe and assign the names.

```
inds <- is.na(names(df))
names(df)[inds] <- df[1, inds]


df
#  Sr. No. Media Vehicle        Location Size  H  Qty Area Start Date End Date Duration     CTU Display Cost 2
#4    <NA>          <NA>            <NA>    W  H <NA> <NA>       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>  Vendor Display Cost 8
#5       1           FOB WEH, Nr. Oberoi   60 10    1  600   01.01.19 31.01.19       30 Capital       900000 0
```